# How does CloudFlare Handle JS Redirects?

Tags: redirects, javascript, cloudflare

I need to implement a couple Javascript redirects using `window.location` on my site. This redirect fires in very specific circumstances and I don't want that redirect cached.

I found info about how CloudFlare handles 301s and 302s but how will it respond to JS redirecting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare will cache a JS redirect just like it caches a normal HTML page, because a JS redirect is a normal HTML page. If you don't want CloudFlare to cache particular JS redirecting code, I suggest you use a page rule to specify that you do not want the HTML/JS that initiates the redirect cached.

Comment: Thank you—I'm ok with the destination page being cached by CF. Will the redirect response itself be cached so that future visits to that page will be redirected by CloudFlare to the redirect destination or will the logic in the JS script still run and decide if that user is redirected? Thanks!

Comment: In the case of a JS redirect, the redirect *is* the originating page and JS, with its 200 response(s). There is no redirect status code in a JS redirect, because the redirect is handled in the script itself rather than by any server status code. Since the redirect *is* the page with the JS, whether you cache that page/JS will determine whether the redirect code is cached. In any case, the JS will run every time the user visits the page that has the JS on it - `window.location` doesn't do anything funky to the browser's caching behavior.